# The value of the array is being shown in the console window but i am not being able to access the individual elements of that particular array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written the following piece of code to fetch the value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var datesize = '<?php echo $cat; ?>';
console.log(datesize);
console.log(datesize);
var oi="'"+ datesize +"'";
var aq=document.getElementsByClassName('calendar');
console.log(aq);
document.getElementById("1").style.border = "20px solid black"; 
 var er=document.getElementById('1');    
while(datesize<4){    
  document.getElementsByClassName('calendar')[datesize].style.display="none";    
  datesize++;
}
</script>
```

by logging the variable aq in console log i get the following objects

```
0:div#0.calendar.next
1:div#1.calendar
2:div#2.calendar
3:div#3.calendar
```

When I try to log using aq[1]
I get the value as undefined .
How can I access each and every individual element in that array?

Comment: share your html

Comment: you could have simply used while(datesize<4){    
  aq[datesize].style.display="none";    
  datesize++;
}

Comment: When you are accessing aq[1], does it still hold the elements array you added before? Its totally fine accessing aq[1] in an array of four objects. You just have to loop over it like for(i=0;i<aq.length;i++){var obj = aq[i];})